# Sharepoint 2010 adding multiple values to a Managed Metadata column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata

Having a problem with the code below only adds the latest value in the TestTaxonomyControl.Text to the metadata column. ( multiple values is turned on )

```
  TaxonomyFieldValueCollection values = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(String.Empty);
            values.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(TestTaxonomyControl.Text);
         TaxonomyField entKeyword = (TaxonomyField)item.Fields["Metadata"];
            foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue value in values)
            {  
                TaxonomyFieldValue term = new TaxonomyFieldValue("1;#" + value.Label + "|" + value.TermGuid);

                entKeyword.SetFieldValue(item, term);
            }
            item.Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you only need something like:

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection values = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(String.Empty);             
values.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(TestTaxonomyControl.Text); 
item["Metadata"] = values;
item.Update();
```

Comment: What format would I use for Enterprise Keywords Metadata column ?

Comment: Enterprise Keywords will not take format like "Laxman|5732ee9b-cd43-425c-bc94-d356b5c44e1d" or  "1;#test|5732ee9b-cd43-425c-bc94-d356b5c44e1d"

Comment: Hmm. I think the best thing would be if you formulated a new question with as much info as possible. That way, a lot more people would see and be able to help you.

Comment: Never mind It worked anyway, Thank you so much I was looking everywhere for this for weeks. :)